# Where to correct an inefficiency of algorithm in a published paper?

Tags: publications

I spotted a serious inefficiency in our algorithm, which was already published. Basically, we have an algorithm to encode a problem A into a formula X. But we later found that we can encode into a formula X', which is equisatisfiable, but with much less (up to thousand) of variables.

This change is very trivial in logic, if we need to correct the algorithm, we only need to change 1 line with one subscript. But it improve the performance drastically, up to 10 times in some instances.

If somebody build on our work, I don't want them to make the same mistake. If somebody want to compare with our work, I want them to compare with the improved algorithm, not the result we reported in the paper.

But the change is so trivial, how could I let everybody know?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The change only appears trivial to you now that you know about it.

Moreover, while the change may be simple, the validation of that change is not: I'm sure there's lots of experiments to run to verify your statement, and maybe some new analyses to be performed as well.

To me, this sounds like a fine opportunity for a followup.  If your paper was published in a conference, then the improved version can go into the "extended version" journal paper.  If your paper was already published in a journal, this is a good time to follow up with a short conference paper.  If you're in a field that doesn't like conferences, there will probably be journals that take "short papers" or "application notes" or some similar.

Bottom line: one way or another, there should be a good place to put this not-as-trivial-as-you-think piece of work.

Comment: _I'm sure there's lots of experiments to run to verify your statement_: really? Why are you sure? Nowhere in the post is anything said that could indicate this, and in fact OP says the change is trivial, which suggests that at least after it is pointed out, it is obviously recognized as correct. Needless to say, if that's true then there isn't any need for a followup paper, unless the new improvement opens up genuinely new directions to explore.

Comment: @DanRomik To quote the original post: *"But it improves the performance drastically, up to 10 times in some instances."*  That statement implies 1) experimental testing and 2) a potentially significant dependency on problem structure that is probably worth elucidating.

Answer (score 3):

Most journals have errata for published papers.  Contact the journal and ask them how you can amend your paper with the updated algorithm.  They will likely simply post the erratum you provide to the online version and put a note in the next issue of the print version with the revision.

Comment: But there is no error, this is just inefficiency. And the paper was published in a conference (I'm in Computer Science).

Comment: Errata don't necessarily imply "incorrect".  Inefficiency that is improved would still be published as an erratum to the article.  Conferences often do the same thing as journals.  Depends on the conference.

Comment: I would call this an *addendum* rather than an *erratum*.

Comment: I would call it "addendum" too. I was referring to the section, not the modification.  Some journals have separate errata and addenda, but most put them both under the former's header.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a prime opportunity for a second publication!

In all seriousness, you can cover/publicize this through a white paper. It has the benefit of being picked up by Google Scholar and should be found by anyone doing a literature survey of your work. Most universities have a method of publishing white papers or you could use a service like arXiv.

If you'd like to generate a little more publicity, throw up a blog post or some sort of social media post as appropriate to your field (i.e. Twitter, Reddit, etc.).

Comment: Your suggestion for a white paper is not necessarily a bad idea now that I understand what you mean. However the first sentence of your answer only makes sense as a joke, and it was initially not obvious to me that that's what it was (even now I'm not entirely sure). I recommend removing that sentence, and maybe clarifying (assuming that's what you mean, again I'm not completely sure) that the white paper and social media suggestions are meant to get the community to learn about the improvement to the algorithm rather than as self-promotion for the OP.